# How to prevent child re-render on every parent state update done though input field in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am building a basic chat application. I have a parent component (`Console.js`) that contains three child components

- QuestionCard.js
- AnswerCard.js
- InputCard.js

This is how the basic layout looks like

```
const Console = () => {
    // initial state for input field
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");

    // fetch previous conversation history
    const conversationHistory = useSelector(state=> state.conversationHistory.data)

    conversationHistory.map((info, idx) => (
        
    info.type == "statement" ? 
        <span key={idx}>
            <QuestionCard    
                data={info}
                
            />
         
        </span>

    : info.type == "answer" ?
        <span key={idx}>
            <AnswerCard 
                userInput={userInput}
                setUserInput={setUserInput}
                data={info}
            />
        </span>
    :
        <span></span>

    ))

    <InputCard
        userInput={userInput}
        setUserInput={setUserInput}
    />
}
```

Specifically in the **InputCard.js** child component, there resides the `input` field where the user types

```
const InputCard = ({userInput, setUserInput}) => {
    const handleTextBoxInput = e => {   
        setUserInput(e.target.value)
    
    }

    return (
        <input
             type="text" 
             value={userInput || ""}
             onChange={handleInput}
             id="userQuery"        
         />           
    )
}
```

The problem here is that every time I press a key, all the child components (**QuestionCard.js**, **AnswerCard.js**, **InputCard.js**) re-renders.

I read about `memo` and it is one way to ensure components don't re-render but needs something to compare against. So I understand I need to compare the `userInput` state before and after and check if indeed something changed. But I just don't know where do I do this comparison or whether to even use `memo`

Can anybody help me with this?

**Note:** I understand I can put the `setState` inside the `InputCard` component and re-rendering will stop but as you can see, I need the `setState` variables inside the `AnswerCard` too for some processing.

Comment: I cannot see your InputCard. Also, if AnswerCard has the input from QuestionCard, won't it render everytime input is changed?

Comment: @tushar sorry I had put a wrong component name. Fixed it.

Comment: Is data an object or a primitive. Also the same thing, if input is changed, AnswerCard will rerender right. Because it has input as a prop.

Comment: I don't any reference to `InputCard` in your sample code

Comment: @tushar you are right. That is the problem. The answer cards re-renders everytime I type something. But I also need the input state to some operation in answer card. How do I solve this? Also data is an object.

Comment: @psygik can you check again?

Comment: @SouvikRay so there is no way you can stop InputCard from rerendering. It depends on `userInput`, hope you understand that. You can have some performance optimization on `AnswerCard`, if you compare your data using React.memo 2nd parameter. That depends on your structure of data. Can you share that? How deeply nested is it.

Comment: Are you actually observing a problem (performance of logical)? If not, then this question doesn't need answering. This is how react works and it's very fast out of the box. Don't optimize until you need to.

Answer (score 4):

That's how React works AFAIK. A change in props, triggers a render of the component.

That said,

Here are some suggestions for your problem:

### Debounce

One of the common patterns around handling user input is to debounce it. This prevents the component re-render on every key press.
You can tailor the debounce timer to suit your use-case:

```js
const Border = {
  RED: {
    border: '1px solid red',
    margin: '12px 0',
    padding: '4px'
  },
  GREEN: {
    border: '1px solid green',
    margin: '12px 0',
    padding: '4px'
  },
  BLUE: {
    border: '1px solid blue',
    margin: '12px 0',
    padding: '4px'
  },
  MAGENTA: {
    border: '1px solid magenta',
    margin: '12px 0',
    padding: '4px'
  }
};

const MARGIN = { margin: '12px' };

function useDebounce(value, delay) {
  // State and setters for debounced value
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = React.useState(value);

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      // Update debounced value after delay
      const handler = setTimeout(() => {
        setDebouncedValue(value);
      }, delay);

      // Cancel the timeout if value changes (also on delay change or unmount)
      // This is how we prevent debounced value from updating if value is changed ...
      // .. within the delay period. Timeout gets cleared and restarted.
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(handler);
      };
    },
    [value, delay] // Only re-call effect if value or delay changes
  );

  return debouncedValue;
}

const useRenderCounter = (thing) => {
  const renderCount = React.useRef(1);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    renderCount.current += 1;
  });
  return `Render count for ${thing} ${renderCount.current}`;
};

const InputCard = ({ userInput, setUserInput }) => {
  const renderCount = useRenderCounter('InputCard');
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState(userInput);
  const debouncedValue = useDebounce(input, 750);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setUserInput(debouncedValue);
  }, [debouncedValue]);

  return (
    <div style={Border.MAGENTA}>
      <span>{renderCount}</span>
      <div style={MARGIN}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={input}
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          id="userQuery"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const QuestionCard = ({ userInput, setUserInput }) => {
  const renderCount = useRenderCounter('QuestionCard');
  return (
    <div style={Border.RED}>
      <span>{renderCount}</span>
      <div style={MARGIN}>User Input: {userInput}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const AnswerCard = ({ userInput, setUserInput }) => {
  const renderCount = useRenderCounter('AnswerCard');
  return (
    <div style={Border.GREEN}>
      <span>{renderCount}</span>
      <div style={MARGIN}>User Input: {userInput}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const renderCount = useRenderCounter('App');
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <div style={Border.BLUE}>
      <span>{renderCount}</span>
      <QuestionCard userInput={userInput} setUserInput={setUserInput} />
      <AnswerCard userInput={userInput} setUserInput={setUserInput} />
      <InputCard userInput={userInput} setUserInput={setUserInput} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
span {
  padding: 4px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

### useRef

However, *if you need the other components to not re-render on entering text*, you can leverage `useRef` hook and keep track of the user input without having to re-render the component tree.

But bear in mind, with this approach, in order for other components to **show the updated value on the DOM**,
there has to be a trigger to cause a re-render. In the example, the state is updated on button click
which then triggers the re-render. Since you mentioned you are building a chat app, maybe you'd find this pattern useful.

```js
const Border = {
  RED: {
    border: '1px solid red',
    margin: '12px 0',
    padding: '4px'
  },
  GREEN: {
    border: '1px solid green',
    margin: '12px 0',
    padding: '4px'
  },
  BLUE: {
    border: '1px solid blue',
    margin: '12px 0',
    padding: '4px'
  },
  MAGENTA: {
    border: '1px solid magenta',
    margin: '12px 0',
    padding: '4px'
  }
};

const MARGIN = { margin: '12px' };

const useRenderCounter = (thing) => {
  const renderCount = React.useRef(1);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    renderCount.current += 1;
  });
  return `Render count for ${thing} ${renderCount.current}`;
};

const InputCard = ({ userInput, setUserInput }) => {
  const renderCount = useRenderCounter('InputCard');
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState(userInput);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setUserInput(input);
  }, [input]);

  return (
    <div style={Border.MAGENTA}>
      <span>{renderCount}</span>
      <div style={MARGIN}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={input}
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          id="userQuery"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const QuestionCard = ({ userInput, setUserInput }) => {
  const renderCount = useRenderCounter('QuestionCard');
  return (
    <div style={Border.RED}>
      <span>{renderCount}</span>
      <div style={MARGIN}>User Input: {userInput}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const AnswerCard = ({ userInput, setUserInput }) => {
  const renderCount = useRenderCounter('AnswerCard');
  return (
    <div style={Border.GREEN}>
      <span>{renderCount}</span>
      <div style={MARGIN}>User Input: {userInput}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const renderCount = useRenderCounter('App');
  const inputRef = React.useRef('');
  const setUserInput = (input) => {
    inputRef.current = input;
  };

  const [submit, onSubmit] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <div style={Border.BLUE}>
      <span>{renderCount}</span>
      <QuestionCard userInput={inputRef.current} setUserInput={setUserInput} />
      <AnswerCard userInput={inputRef.current} setUserInput={setUserInput} />
      <InputCard userInput={inputRef.current} setUserInput={setUserInput} />
      <button type="submit" onClick={() => onSubmit(inputRef.current)}>
        Trigger Render
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
span {
  padding: 4px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

### `React.memo()`

`React.memo()` is used to memoize a component, based on the dependencies passed to it. It takes a component as a prop and returns a component that prevents a component from re-rendering if the props (or values within it) have not changed.

It is important to keep in mind that your code must not depend on `React.memo()` just to avoid re-renders. You should be able to replace `React.memo()` with direct component calls and it must not affect anything else, except performance.

> This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs. - [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

I honestly do not see any benefits by using a memo for your case. Anyways, this is ideally how you can memoize a component:

```
  const QuestionCardMemoized = React.memo(
    () => QuestionCard({ userInput, setUserInput }),
    [userInput, setUserInput]
  );

  const AnswerCardMemoized = React.memo(
    () => AnswerCard({ userInput, setUserInput }),
    [userInput, setUserInput]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <QuestionCardMemoized />
      <AnswerCardMemoized />
      <InputCard userInput={userInput} setUserInput={setUserInput} />
    </div>
  );
```

Do keep in mind that React is VERY fast. Unless you see any performance issues by measuring using profiler tools, I'd say spend your time on something more useful than unnecessary/pre-mature optimization.